# Is there a built in way to serialize array configuration values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, config.json

I'm on a new ASP.NET 5 project.

I'm trying to read an array value, stored in my `config.json` file, that looks like this:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "SiteTitle": "MyProject",
    "Tenants": {
      "ReservedSubdomains": ["www", "info", "admin"]
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-MyProject....."
    }
  }
}
```

How do I access this from my C# code?

Comment: Just FYI...you could use a VS feature(probably VS 2013 onwards) called "Paste as JSON classes" which will generate C# classes from the copied json in your clipboard..this will give you a starting point and you can modify the classes as you may like

Comment: @KiranChalla, obviously I don't want to copy paste, I want to keep my code clean and soft-coded.

Comment: Not sure what you meant, I didn't mean to just use the generated code right away...you can modify it as you may need but keeping in the mind of the deserialization semantics..

Comment: @KiranChalla it has to be done programmatically at runtime, not at design time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least with beta4 arrays aren't supported in `config.json`.  See [ASP.NET issue 620](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/620).  But you could use the following `config.json`:

```
"AppSettings": {
  "SiteTitle": "MyProject",
  "Tenants": {
    "ReservedSubdomains": "www, info, admin"
  }
}
```

and map it to a class like this:

```
public class AppSettings
{
  public string SiteTitle { get; set; }
  public AppSettingsTenants Tenants { get; set; } = new AppSettingsTenants();
}

public class AppSettingsTenants
{
  public string ReservedSubdomains { get; set; }
  public List<string> ReservedSubdomainList
  {
     get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReservedSubdomains) ? ReservedSubdomains.Split(',').ToList() : new List<string>(); }
  }
}
```

This can then be injected into a controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

  public MyController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
  {
     _appSettings = appSettings.Options;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I ended up, but I prefer my code to be as clean as possible, and the right choice here is array. Did you read [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/33) announcement?

Comment: cool. sounds like it will be available in beta5.  For now I'm working around the limitation as shown above.

Comment: @jitrem, and BTW, since I see you're an AppSettings guru, check out my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31563575/75500), I'm sure you'll have what to add.