# How to create T4 text templates(.tt) in ASP.NET core on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create T4 text templates to achieve code generation. All the tutorials I found on msdn suggest following to add a new text template: `Add > New Item > Text Template`, (eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) but I don't see that option(`Text Template`) there. I am using ASP.NET core 1.0.

Is this issue related to VS2015 or ASP.NET core? If T4 templating is not supported in any of them, what's the best solution/alternative to achieve this?

(I want to generate typescript code from C# code), similar to this tutorial http://dotnetspeak.com/2015/02/typescript-models-creation-via-t4-templates

Comment: I don't think this is fully supported yet. You can add .tt files to .net core class library projects and right click _Run Custom Tool_ on it. It will then be re-generated every time you change the .tt. See this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/272) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563575/design-time-t4-templates-in-asp-net-5-vs-2015)

Comment: Thank you for help. I am new to .net development so excuse me if this question sounds silly. Where/what is .net core class library project?

Comment: When you add a new project to your solution, you can find the .net core class library under Visual C# -> Web -> Class Library (Package). This creates a library that you can use in other .net core projects (which can be libraries or other types of projects like a web site or a console application)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was a bug in the visual studio in the early stages.

Now, with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (and I think with Update 2 too) I can easily run T4 templates, even in .NET Core / ASP.NET Core projects.

If there isn't the Add > New Item > Text Template option, you can add *.tt files as simple text files.

Give it a try. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, appreciate it. There isn't `Add > New Item > Text Template`, but will try adding `*.tt` files. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Let me know about your success :)

Comment: Hey @TóthTibor and MatthiasBurger sorry for late reply, my initial attempt did not work, and due to some other reasons I haven't been able to work on this recently. I will update asap if I make progress.

Comment: @TóthTibor and MatthiasBurger, I am able to generate text template now. Though VS 2015 doesn't give me an option to add "Text Template" file, I simply created a new file, and saved it as `.tt`, then it's functioning as a text template. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: November 2019, VS 2019, ASP.Net Core 3.0. It still **IS** a bug there.

Comment: September 2020 VS community edition. Still couldn't add TT file to Web project. Just adding Manually.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the "Run Custom Tool" was not appearing when I manually added my TT file to the project. I need to set "Custom Tool" to "TextTemplatingFileGenerator" on the Properties tab for the TT file.

Right Click on the TT file and select Properties
[image]